# Why print_r is not working as expected in this case

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to show the content of array into my error log when one Exception occurs.

I don't understand why `print_r` is not working as expected in this code:

```
throw new ExcepcionApi(BAD_URL, ("Bad URL: {print_r($peticion,TRUE)}"));
```

In the log file:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ExcepcionApi: Bad URL: {print_r(Array,TRUE)} in / ...
```

This works fine:

```
$errorMsg=print_r($peticion,TRUE);
throw new ExcepcionApi(BAD_URL, ("Bad URL: $errorMsg"));
```

In the log file:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ExcepcionApi: Bad URL: Array
(
    [0] => fakeURL
    [1] => fakeParams
)
```

Why `print_r` not works in the first case?

Comment: Because php can extract function call from a string? What if you string will be `"I print print print"`? What php should do? Call `print` 3 times?

Comment: @u_mulder but in functions as `mysqli_error()` and other functions it works...

Comment: Maybe you mix function call and method call from instance

Comment: _“but in functions as mysqli_error() and other functions it works”_ - what _exactly_ works for those?

Comment: @u_mulder this will work for example: `"Error: {mysqli_error()}"`

Comment: No, this won't. And here's why https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: did you have tried to break the string? `("Bad URL: {".print_r($peticion,TRUE)."}")`

Comment: @u_mulder OK OK, I was confused, in normal code I save the messages into variables and I use functions inside, for example: `$msg="Error: mysqli_error()";` but I don't print that directly, I use: `echo $msg;`  I think you can write one response if you want. Thanks.

Comment: `echo "Error: mysqli_error()";` will __not work__ too. You obviously doing something else or just have bugged code.

Comment: Use the famous sprintf like so: `throw new ExcepcionApi(BAD_URL, sprintf("Bad URL: %s", print_r($peticion,TRUE)));`

Comment: @mitkosoft I know that concatenating it works, but I asked because i don't understand why second code not works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex):

> **Note:**
>   Functions, method calls, static class variables, and class constants
>   inside {$} work since PHP 5. However, the value accessed will be
>   interpreted as the name of a variable in the scope in which the string
>   is defined. Using single curly braces ({}) will not work for accessing
>   the return values of functions or methods or the values of class
>   constants or static class variables.

That means you can use function and method calls inside the expression but only to obtain a variable name, e.g.:

```
  $myvar = "Hello";

  function whichvar() {
    return "myvar"; // Returns a variable name
  }

  // gets variable by a name from the function
  print "Result is: {${whichvar()}}"; // Result is: Hello
```

or to obtain array index etc.

```
  $myarr = array(
    'notthis' => 'Bad',
    'andnotthistoo' => 'Too Bad',
    'this' => 'Good'
  );

  function whichidx() {
    return 'this';
  }

  print "I like {$myarr[whichidx()]}"; // I like Good
```

But it is not possible to get result of the function itself.

And actually I do not understand why you need it in the first place. You always can use simple string concatenation using `.` operator:

```
throw new ExcepcionApi(BAD_URL, ("Bad URL: " . print_r($peticion,TRUE)));
```